# Display Ansible playbook with lookups interpolated

Tags: ansible, string-interpolation

I have an Ansible playbook that looks, in part, like this:

```
...
environment:
  F2B_DB_PURGE_AGE: "{{ lookup('env','F2B_DB_PURGE_AGE') }}"
  F2B_LOG_LEVEL: "{{ lookup('env','F2B_LOG_LEVEL') }}"
  SSMTP_HOST: "{{ lookup('env','SSMTP_HOST') }}"
  SSMTP_PORT: "{{ lookup('env','SSMTP_PORT') }}"
  SSMTP_TLS: "{{ lookup('env','SSMTP_TLS') }}"
...
```

Is there any way to run `ansible-playbook` so that it will show the results of the YAML file after replacing the lookups with their values? That is, I would like to be able to run something like `ansible-playbook file.yaml --dry-run` and see on standard output (assuming the environment variables were set appropriately):

```
...
environment:
  F2B_DB_PURGE_AGE: "20"
  F2B_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
  SSMTP_HOST: "smtp.example.com"
  SSMTP_PORT: "487"
  SSMTP_TLS: "true"
...
```

Comment: Debugging the value of `environment` will give you the expanded result. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html

Comment: Debugging the value of `environment` is a useful tip, but I was hoping to have `ansible-playbook` do the work for me. I could have more complicated examples, say where the interpolated value is a complicated file path composed of several environment variables.

Comment: ... in which case you just have to debug the variable holding your complicated example path composed of several env vars and you will get the result as well. Note that running ansible in verbose mode `-vvv` will print loads of information on each task and might print what you need depending where things are defined and which task your are playing. Note as well that the `debug` module as a verbosity option to obey the number of `-v`s on the ansible command line.

Comment: Now that I think about it, maybe a Python wrapper script could be written that loads the necessary Ansible modules and does the Jinja interpolation...

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment for testing

```
shell> cat env.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
export F2B_DB_PURGE_AGE="20"
export F2B_LOG_LEVEL="debug"
export SSMTP_HOST="smtp.example.com"
export SSMTP_PORT="487"
export SSMTP_TLS="true"
shell> source env.sh
```

Given the inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

---

Q: ***"Run something like `ansible-playbook file.yaml --dry-run` and see `environment`"***

A: The below playbook does the job

```yaml
shell> cat file.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_environment:
      F2B_DB_PURGE_AGE: "{{ lookup('env','F2B_DB_PURGE_AGE') }}"
      F2B_LOG_LEVEL: "{{ lookup('env','F2B_LOG_LEVEL') }}"
      SSMTP_HOST: "{{ lookup('env','SSMTP_HOST') }}"
      SSMTP_PORT: "{{ lookup('env','SSMTP_PORT') }}"
      SSMTP_TLS: "{{ lookup('env','SSMTP_TLS') }}"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: |
              my_environment:
                {{ my_environment|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
        - meta: end_play
      when: dry_run|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        msg: Continue ...
```

Set *`dry_run=true`*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook file.yml -e dry_run=true

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    my_environment:
      F2B_DB_PURGE_AGE: '20'
      F2B_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      SSMTP_HOST: smtp.example.com
      SSMTP_PORT: '487'
      SSMTP_TLS: 'true'

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

By default, the playbook will execute *`tasks`*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook file.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Continue ...

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Optionally, let the playbook gather facts and use the dictionary *ansible_env*. Use the filer [*ansible.utils.keep_keys*](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.utils#filter-plugins) to select your variables

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

  vars:

    my_environment_vars:
      - F2B_DB_PURGE_AGE
      - F2B_LOG_LEVEL
      - SSMTP_HOST
      - SSMTP_PORT
      - SSMTP_TLS
    my_environment: "{{ ansible_env|
                        ansible.utils.keep_keys(target=my_environment_vars) }}"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: |
              my_environment:
                {{ my_environment|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
        - meta: end_play
      when: dry_run|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        msg: Continue ...
```

---